# What other than login and sudo is a Linux password for?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, sudo

I've got a Linux development machine on which I've given some people key-based ssh access (password login is disabled). The users I've given access do not have sudo rights.

So today I was wondering, since the users cannot login using their password and also can't use sudo, what else can they use their Linux password for?

Answer (score 0):

The password has only authentication purpose. Even if they are granted with key based access, it's a good idea to have an alternative authentication method (meaning in this case the user's password).

The password strenght is also important when using key based access, as if someone tries to break into the machine (assuming they don't have the SSH key), the password must be strong enough to avoid brute-force attacks.

In short, even if your users don't use it explicitly, there's always a reason to set a strong password for accounts.

Comment: So if I'm reading your answer correctly, the answer to my question is "the password is for nothing else logging in and using sudo" rigth? Thanks for highlighting the importance of good passwords though. :-)